# Iterate over *str vs str[] in while loop in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, while-loop, c-strings

I start learning C while ago and I was wondering... Does iterating over a string using

```
char *str = "Hello";
while (*str)
{
     str++;
}
```

Same as

```
char *str = "Hello";
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: No when the string is longer than the maximum value of `int`.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "same". The iteration is the same but the first one ends up with a modified `str` pointer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So the expression `*str` is equivalent to `str[0]`. Or `str[1]` is equivalent tp `*( str + 1 )` that in turn is equivalent to `*( ++str + 0 )` or `*++str` or to the combination of the expressions `++str` and `*str`

The only essential difference is that after this loop

```
char *str = "Hello";
while (*str)
{
     str++;
}
```

the pointer `str` does not point to the beginning of the string literal `"Hello"`. While in the second code snippet

```
char *str = "Hello";
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
```

the pointer `str` is unchanged and points to the first character of the string literal.

Pay attention to that instead of declaring the variable `i` as having the signed type `int` it is better to declare it as having type `size_t` because in general objects of the type `int` can be not large enough to store all possible lengths of strings.

The expression in the while loop of the second code snippet can be written similarly to the expression in the while loop in the first code snippet

```
while ( str[i])
```

or like

```
while ( *( str + i ) )
```

That is any non-zero value is considered as a true expression.

If you do not want to change the original pointer `str` in the first code snippet you can introduce an intermediate pointer like

```
char *str = "Hello";

char *p = str;
while ( *p )
{
     p++;
}
```

For example the function `strlen` can be implemented the following way

```
size_t strlen( const char *s )
{
    const char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: Best explanation I have read so far on SO!

Answer (score 0):

In general, iterating with a string pointer gives the same characters as incrementing a string pointer and dereferencing it.

So, the only differences are the side effects, changing *i* vs changing the str pointer.

Answer (score -1):

I think using *str will include the character '\0' since it's stored in the memory at the last place in the array.

Comment: What do you mean by "include the character"? It will stop the loop when it gets to that NUL character. Which is the same as the second example.